# Telerik Kendo TimePicker Min / Max setting get ignored

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have two Kendo TimePicker: `from` and `to`

What I was trying to achieve is to use JavaScript to change the range of the drop down list options of these TimePickers. Both TimePickers' interval is 30 minutes, from 00:00 to 23:30.

For example, if one choose `from` to 14:30, then the options when `to` is opened will be at least 14:30. Similarly, if one choose `to` to 20:00, then the maximum option of `from` is 20:00

I have written my code and everything seems okay **except** when both `from` and `to` choose the last option (23:30),  the expected behavior is the options of `to` is only 23:30 itself.  However,  in reality the options of `to` is all time span which is of 30 minutes interval, starting from 23:30, to 23:00  (i.e.  23:30, 00:00, 00:30, ... 23:00)

[image]

I have tried many other "combinbations" including both set to 00:00, all shows correct behavior, except this case. I wonder if it is a known bug of the Telerik control, or is there anything wrong in my code? How can I implement the expected behavior?

```js
var $start = $startSel.data("kendoDateTimePicker");
var $end = $endSel.data("kendoDateTimePicker");

var start = $startSel.val() == "" ? null : $start.value();
var end = $endSel.val() == "" ? null : $end.value();

if (start != null) {
  $end.min(comLib.ceilTo30Minute(start));
} else {
  $end.min(new Date(1900, 0, 1));
  $end.max(new Date(2099, 11, 31));
}
if (end != null) {
  $start.max(comLib.floorTo30Minute(end));
} else {
  $start.min(new Date(1900, 0, 1));
  $start.max(new Date(2099, 11, 31));
}


///////////////////// in comLib

function ceilTo30Minute (dateTime) {
   if (dateTime == null)
     return null;
   var min = dateTime.getMinutes() % 30;
   if (min != 0)
   {
     dateTime = publicAccess.addTime(dateTime, 0, -min);
     dateTime = publicAccess.addTime(dateTime, 0, 30);
   }
   return dateTime;
};
function floorTo30Minute(dateTime) {
  if (dateTime == null)
    return null;
  var min = dateTime.getMinutes() % 30;
  if (min != 0) {
    dateTime = publicAccess.addTime(dateTime, 0, -min);
  }
  return dateTime;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have opened a support ticket and Telerik has replied me, turns out it seems like a Kendo UI bug.  Here I am quoting their reply:

> This seems to be a bug in the DateTimePicker and I will forward it to our developers team for further investigation. For the time being you could handle the open event of the second DateTimePicker and manually hide the unwanted times:

```
datetimepicker.bind("open", function(e) {
    if (e.view === "time" && e.sender.min().toString().indexOf("23:30:00") >= 0) {      
        var times = e.sender.timeView.popup.element.find("li");
        for(var i=1; i < times.length; i++){
            $(times[i]).hide();
        }
    }
});
```